# Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version wehn installing react-native-vision-camera

Tags: react-native, kotlin, gradle, react-native-vision-camera

I have a react native app and it builds fine.  However, when I try to install react-native-vision-camera, it failes to build with this message.

```
> Task :react-native-vision-camera:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/chuy/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7deeafea6d161ff761d4ca76f8dcca61/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/chuy/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/35a54be3f0ff5b406b46c3399384ac55/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    /Users/chuy/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/40340d0266c697f483e4d8d82154afae/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    /Users/chuy/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/9c17178342127ce37680d07133a88d55/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
```

Any thoughts on what this could be?

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

This is what RN native I am running and the version of the package

```
"react-native": "0.64.2",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.4",
```